# Using the vtkInteractorStyleFlight in VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

I was on the [VTK c++ examples site](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx) and came across the [flight interactor style](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Broken/Interaction/Flight). I want/need to be able to use some of the features of this tool, but it it not working correctly, or it's not finished? The main problem is that you can see where you end up after you move, but it does not show you the movement. It just jumps from one spot to the next when you release the key/mouse button.

So my question is, is it possible for me to "fix" the VTK class itself? and if so how? (I would prefer this so that others may benefit) Or if that is not possible, how would I go about implementing this type of movement in my program without the vtkInteractorStyleFlight?

Comment: VTK is an open source project and on their page they say how you could contribute. Regarding your problem, add sample code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The "flight interactor style" link is the code that demonstrates my issue.

Comment: The first line there sums it up: "This example is currently broken. The sphere disappears if you click the left mouse button. The arrow keys do nothing." I think they should be happy if you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it yourself:

VTK is on github. To contribute to VTK you will need to create a pull request on github. [link](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)

You will need to edit [vtkInteractorStyleFlight.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Style/vtkInteractorStyleFlight.cxx). The best reference to have is probably [vtkInteractorStyleJoystickCamera.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Style/vtkInteractorStyleJoystickCamera.cxx) because this is the default interactor style created by vtkRenderWindowInteractor.

I personally would be stoked if you take this on.